# column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have submissions, users, stories, and views tables in postgreSQL (among others) as follows:

```
submissions
-----------
user_id
story_id
body

views
-----------
user_id
submissions_id

users
-----------
username
```

I have a complicated find by SQL query that returns submissions ordered by whether or not the user has seen it (has an entry for user_id and submission_id in the views table), and then by how many views it has:

```
    submissions.find_by_sql("select submissions.*,
          count(views.submission_id) as views_count,
          (select count(*) from views
            where views.user_id=#{user_id} and views.submission_id=submissions.id group by id) as counted
          from submissions
          left outer join views on views.submission_id=submissions.id
          where submissions.story_id = #{id}
          group by submissions.id
          order by counted desc, views_count")
```

I would like to also be able to get the username for each submission, which should be easy: just join the users table at users.id=submissions.user_id and add users.username to the select portion.  However, when I do this, I receive an error

```
column "users.username" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

This shouldn't be, as adding users to group by would remove multiplesubmissions that have the same user, and I have no need for an aggregate function.

And since I apparently have to state this explicitly, I'm aware that there are many other questions asking about this, and none of them actually answer my issue.

Comment: And almost [a hundred others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby-on-rails%5D+%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause).

Comment: I looked at around 10 of these before I posted.  They all deal with something different than what I'm asking, and none of them answer my problem.

Comment: Which of the standard solutions did you try and why couldn't you get them to work?

Comment: Adding users to `GROUP BY` would *not* remove multiple submissions. Adding more items to `GROUP BY` *never* removes more duplicates. Only the opposite is possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `group by` clause, in most systems you are restricted to 
only showing the fields in the `group by` clause in your `select` statement.  Plus any aggregating columns using `count(), sum(),` etc

Try another query wrapped around your original query:

```
select * from 
(
select top 100 percent 
          submissions.id,
          count(views.submission_id) as views_count,
          (select count(*) from views
            where views.user_id=#{user_id} and views.submission_id=submissions.id group by id) as counted
          from submissions
          left outer join views on views.submission_id=submissions.id
          where submissions.story_id = #{id}
          group by submissions.id
          order by counted desc, views_count
) as InnerQuery
left join submissions on submissions.ID = InnerQuery.ID
```

Comment: I ended up adding users.username to group by, which should have removed multiple posts with like users, but didn't.  I don't understand why group by matters, or why adding users.userrname to it actually worked.

Comment: @andrewkostka the order by which you put Fields in the group by Clause makes all the difference.  You can use GROUP BY COL1, COL2 which Will be completely different to GROUP BY COL2, COL1. Always look at it going from left to right, which dictates which is grouped first, then grouped secondly.... Make sense?  Did you try the full query I posted? That should work